# Parsing List of Strings from Scala future JSON response

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm not too experienced in Scala, so I'm having a little trouble parsing what I want to parse from the following.

Currently, I make a request to retrieve Facebook friends given an access token:

```
val duration = Duration(10, SECONDS)
val future: Future[play.api.libs.ws.Response] = WS.url("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=" + token).get()
val response = Await.result(future, duration)
```

I have access to the JSON response via response.json. However, the friends are returned in the following format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Person 1",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Person 2",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Person 3",
      "id": "3"
    } ...
  ],
  "paging": {  
     ...
  }
}
```

I know that I can retrieve the "data" dictionary by means of "(response.json \ "data")", but is there a way for me to parse this JSON in a way that I could obtain all of the ids in data as a List?

Answer (score 5):

This will work:

```
response.json \ "data" \\ "id"
```

From the documentation of the `\\` operator:

> Lookup for fieldName in the current object and all descendants.

Comment: Thanks Marius, didn't know I could access them in a collection like that. This returns me a List of JsValues - is it possible to convert that into a List of Strings?

Comment: Yes, you can do something like this to get the list of strings: `(response.json \ "data" \\ "id").map(_.as[String])`

Comment: I just tried it out, with the following error returned:
"type mismatch; found : Seq[String] required: List[String]"

Comment: Try this: `(json \ "data" \\ "id").map(_.as[String]).toList`